# Solution for cloud hosting images on EE3?

Tags: assets, image, ee3, hosting

I'm have been using P&T Assets to easily integrate with Amazon S3. Is there any option out there for cloud hosting and EE3? Can I still use Assets?

Answer (score 1):

there is a brandnew add-on called treasury wich supports assets storage on S3.
https://buzzingpixel.com/software/treasury

It is also compatible with Ansel (https://buzzingpixel.com/software/ansel-ee) which makes image handling working like a charme!

Answer (score 0):

Assets, although in development, is not out for EE3 yet. As far as I know, [CE Image](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-image) and [Channel Images](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/channel-images) are the only other add-ons currently available for EE3 which integrate with S3 and other cloud storage platforms.